# $f$ and $g$ are lower semicontinuous functions and their sum $f+g$ is continuous then each of the function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am not sure about the following result.

> If $f$ and $g$ are two lower semi-continuous function and their sum (pointwise) $f+g$ is continuous then both $f$ and $g$ are continuous function.

Is it true?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The sum of two USC functions is USC.  If $f$ is LSC, $- f$ is USC and so is $g = (f+g) + (- f)$.  So $g$ is both USC and LSC, therefore continuous.  Similarly with $f$ and $g$ interchanged.

Comment: when $\ f=0,\ $ why $\ g\ $ is both USC and LSC?

Comment: If $f=0$, $f+g=g$ is continuous means USC and LSC

Comment: Yes, everything is instant here, I had a dark moment. :)

Comment: This theorem and its proof are wonderfully general in their nature!